# Instruction level parallelism vs SIMD

Tags: parallel-processing, simd

What are the similarities and differences between instruction level parallelism and SIMD (ingle instruction, multiple data)? I know that they both work with multiple instructions, but that's the only similarity I can think about.

Answer (score 2):

SIMD is having each instruction process multiple items.  ILP is about having [multiple dependency chains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485733/what-is-the-minimal-number-of-dependency-chains-to-maximize-the-execution-throug) so multiple instructions can be in flight at once.

They are orthogonal; to max out Haswell's FMA throughput, you need to keep 10 FMAs in flight, each one operating on a vector of 8 single-precision elements.

The [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki has lots of links, especially Agner Fog's Optimizing Assembly and microarchitecture guides to understand more about throughput vs. latency.